# How to get all records from my members table which are created at todays date

Tags: sql-server

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT Email FROM members 
    WHERE RoleId = 5 ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC

SELECT Email FROM members 
    WHERE RoleId = 5 ORDER BY CreatedAt

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    members 
WHERE 
    CreatedAt = (SELECT MAX(2016-05-10 20:59:06.837) FROM members)
ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC;
```

Comment: You should try some basic SQL tutorials before posting questions on SO.  This question is very likely to get downvoted for lack of research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all new rows from today....and assuming you always populate the CreatedAt column and assuming it is a datetime you would use something like this.

```
select * 
from members 
where CreatedAt > convert(date, getdate())
```

Comment: If that works you should consider marking it as the answer.